# How to See the content of Decompiled code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I am trying to obfuscate my project. I have used Obfuscator plugin from Unity Asset store. I want to see how my obfuscated code looks like. So I did reverse engineering and got Assembly-CSharp.dll  file. When I open it on DNspy I check my class name, It only shows me method name not method's content. How would I know If my code is obfuscated or not. I am using IL2CPP and .net 4.  Is there any way to see method's content. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3pf3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

IL2CPP basically is converting the c# code to c++ code to be more efficient and gain better performance so the dll you are inspecting using DNSpy is a c++ DLL, reversing c++ code is not impossible but very hard, you can dump only functions names using

[IL2CPP Dumper](https://github.com/Perfare/Il2CppDumper)

the only benefit from using this tool is to get the offset in memory so player can cheat in the game by changing the value of that offset

Answer (score 0):

You are using Unity's "Obfuscator" plugin, but don't know if the code is right or not.
You can try the methods below:

1. Import the Unity package of obfuscator.
2. Click the file to configure obfuscation options.

[image]

3. Enable obfuscated code.

[image]

4. Obfuscate all assemblies.
5. The assembly file name that needs to be obfuscated.
6. The parts of the code that need to be obfuscated, such as class names, method names, parameters and so on.
7. Package the apk.
8. Change the suffix of the apk to rar or other compressed file format that your computer can open and decompress it.
9. Open the corresponding folder "asset>bin>data>managed" to find your obfuscated dll file. Drag it into .NET Reflector to see the obfuscated code.

[image]

[image]

Precautions:

1. The click event of the drag assignment needs to be marked with [SkipRename] or not set the obfuscated method name because the method name will be changed. When you click the button, you will naturally not find the method you dragged up.
2. All data classes need to be marked with [Skip], otherwise the properties inside cannot be called. The name is different from the drag event. Naturally, it cannot be called.
3. If the third-party plug-in fails, see if it is placed in the Plugins folder. The plug-in will not obfuscate the code in the Plugins folder.

Comment: Thank you very much . If I obfuscate Assembly-CSharp.dll, then I am getting few errors. I dont want to obfuscate it , but I want to obfuscate some classes only. Can I do that without obfuscating the complete dll file